# How to validate a form with express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

I just started learning the node.js web framework - express.js and i need a little help of validating a form. I hope you can help me.

Here is my form page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
        <div>

{{ number1 }} + {{ number2 }} = <form action="/" method="POST"> <input type="number" name="result"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Result"/>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is where i route the form.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Test',
     number1: 7,
     number2: 5,
     });

});

router.post('/', function(req, res){
     var result=req.body.result;
     res.send(result+ " is the right answer !");


});

module.exports = router;
```

So its just a simple validation. I have two numbers "5" and "7" and i want when a user type into the number input field the result of 5+7, so when he type 12, to open him a message ("12 is the right answer") and when he type a number different then 12 to give him a error message like ("15 isnt the right answer"). I hope you can help me thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while rendering the form set the two numbers in req.body. Add then up and compare with req.body.result

Something like this ?

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var firstNum = req.body.firstNum;
    var secondNum = req.body.secondNum;    
    var result = req.body.result;

    if(result === firstNum + secondNum) {
      res.send(result+ " is the right answer !");
    } else {
      res.send(result + " isnt the right answer")
    }
});
```